# Notepad++ how to extract only the text field which is needed?

Tags: notepad++, regex-negation

I have a log file which has lot of data. But it would be in similar format.

**Sample text:**

Line 1428: [errormessage] = 21:26:07.629 acceptance criteria not met. Expected:0.0009999871, Actual:0.007407427, Window:[0.007407427]   at Hello.TestAutomation.Tests.Implementation.TestExecution.MirrorTestExecutor.b__12_1(IMonitor m, MonitoringEventArgs e)
Line 1429: [errormessage] = 21:26:07.629 acceptance criteria not met. Expected:0.0009999871, Actual:0.007407427, Window:[0.007407787]   at Hello.TestAutomation.Tests.Implementation.TestExecution.MirrorTestExecutor.b__12_1(IMonitor m, MonitoringEventArgs e)

Now i want to filter text after Window: which is in [ ]: ex for Line 1428, I only need 0.007407427 / [0.007407427] which ever is easy and respectively from the whole log file.

**Expected output:**

0.007407427

0.007407787

Any suggestions? I found a regular expression to detect what i want [([0-9,.]*?)] but how to replace all the other text and only leave this text left.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use capture groups.  Assuming there is only one window per line:

Find field: `^.+Window:\[([0-9,\.]+).+`

Replace field: `\1`